# Significance of __IN__ and __OUT__ qualifiers for parameters in ODBC API's Signature

Tags: c++, visual-c++, odbc

Reading through the Microsoft Implementation of ODBC header file `sql.h`, the parameters of almost all the declarations of the APIs are qualified with `__IN__` or `__OUT__`.

Example

```
SQLRETURN  SQL_API SQLRowCount(_In_ SQLHSTMT StatementHandle,
                               _Out_ SQLLEN* RowCount);
```

I understand, such usage is usually used to determined the direction for transport optimization particularly used in COM world where data needs to be marshaled and UN-marshalled but such usage seems odd in ODBC context.

What is the significance of these qualifiers from ODBC perspective?

Answer (score 0):

Syntactically, there is probably no significance at all.  They both are probably `#define`d to be nothing someplace.  They're just for helping make the API more readable in isolation from the documentation - simply marking which parameters are inputs to the function and which are outputs.

Comment: I fear not. If you have access to the header file, you can see a chain of macro definitions are in place.

Comment: I don't here, no.  Can you show what the ultimate definition ends up being?

Comment: I just compiled with /P option and as you suspected the macro chains ultimately ended up to nothing. But I am still curious if they are just there for documentation or have some ulterior motive?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's just for documentation.  [UEFI](http://www.uefi.org/home/) does something similar.